# Ho do I configure ColdFusion Builder 2 for Stand alone CF+ Tomcat Bundle so that the server can be started and stopped manually from the Server Panel

Tags: coldfusion

I have recently installed ColdFusion 10 developer edition on Windows 7 x64. I don't want to run ColdFusion 10 sever at start-up and in the background as it eats lots of CPU and RAM.

How do I configure ColdFusion Builder so that it can be started and stopped as per need basis (Probably from the ColdFusion Builder's server Panel) ?

I dont want to use Windows Service manager to start the server Every time I need it or Stop it whenever I dont need it.

I also like to know which sites are best for learning CFM ?

Answer (score 0):

Its easy. Just go to CF Builder > Window > Preferences

In the tree list Choose Adobe > RDS Configuration

Click on New button and add your server Information there. But before all of this, you have to be sure that when installation the CF, you have opted-in for the RDS configuration and you remember the RDS password given.